# Rxjs create observable based on another

Tags: rxjs

Here is the code:

```
getActiveUserShares(): Observable<UserTeamShare[]> {
    return this.userService
        .getActiveUser()
        .pipe(flatMap((user) => (user ? this.provider.getUserShares(user.id) : of([]))));
}
```

It throws :

`ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

No idea why.
How do I create observable that when first thing emits it returns and observable thatis based on the first observable?

Comment: What does `this.provider.getUserShares(user.id)` return?

Comment: Observable<UserTeamShare[]]

Comment: Which is the line of code raising the error?

Comment: When doing .subscribe on it

Comment: I switch to an answer to give you more details even if unfortunately it is not a real answer

Answer (score 0):

If `this.provider.getUserShares(user.id)` returns an `Observable<UserTeamShare[]>` you should have `UserTeamShare[]` as the type of the variable defined within the `subscription` method.

For instance, let's consider the following code

```
getActiveUserShares() {
    return this.userService
        .getActiveUser()
        .pipe(flatMap((user) => (user ? this.provider.getUserShares(user.id) : of([]))));
}

getActiveUserShares().submit(data => // do stuff with data)
```

Using intellisense you should see that Typescript tells you that the method `getActiveUserShares` return an `Observable<UserTeamShare[]>` while the variable `data` is of type `UserTeamShare[]`.

If this is the case you should be able to operate with `data`as you would with any array of `UserTeamShare` instances. It this is not the case, than this mean that `this.provider.getUserShares(user.id)` does not returns an `Observable<UserTeamShare[]>`.